# How to make my background image drag behaviour only be draggable to the size of my device and not show the background scaffold color

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]
This is what the page looks like when dragged downwards .

I am trying to make the background image be draggable til the end of the device and not show the background scaffold color when dragging the image downwards .

```
   Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/background.png',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
```